# How to compile SNA (Scala Native Access)

Tags: scala, compilation, jna

I'm new in Scala and Java world, so please to forgive me this simple question.

In my project I want to use native library, which is the interface to the hardware device.
I'm trying to compile SNA (Scala Native Access), but I can't do that.

I downloaded SNA source to folder sna, and JNA jars to folder jna
next cd to D:\sna\src\com\sun\jna\java and try to compile with this command:

javac -cp d:\JNA\jna-4.0.0.jar Structure.java

It gave me following errors:

```
Structure.java:1050: error: cannot find symbol
            if (m.getSize() < requiredSize) {
                 ^
  symbol:   method getSize()
  location: variable m of type Memory
Structure.java:1287: error: cannot find symbol
                StructField sf = ((Union)ref).biggestField;
                                             ^
  symbol:   variable biggestField
  location: class Union
Note: Structure.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors
```

If SNA is even supported by the author?
If it is compatible with actual version of JNA (4.0.0)?

I'm trying this steps on Windows7 64bit.

Comment: JNA 4.0 made some changes to structure usage that are not backward-compatible.  You should either update the SNA code (not a big deal) or link against an older version of JNA.

Comment: relevant: http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/4692

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, only the Structure in JNA is incompatible with Scala class. So if you don't want to patch JNA you can rewrite your Scala class in Java and pass the Java class (which extends Structure) instance into your native function.